# removeVolatile doesn't clear all value in UserDefaults.registrationDomain

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

Today I learn that iOS has a volatile and a persistent store for `UserDefaults`.

I register a value (`value`) with key (`key`) using the `register` method.

```
let key = "key"
let value = "value"
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [key: value])
```

In my application code, I try to delete the key using the `removeObject(forKey:) method`.

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
```

I expect that the next time I try to fetch the value of `key`, the `object(forKey:)` will return `nil` (but it doesn't not).

Full Code:

```
let key = "key"
let value = "value"

UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [key: value])
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(value, forKey: key)
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) // "value" - why?
```

1. From my understanding, the `register` method "registers" values in the [registrationDomain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1415953-registrationdomain), which is temporary until a real value is set (using the `setValue(forKey:)` method). But in this case, even once I set a real value and then delete the value, `object(forKey:)` returns the value from the `registrationDomain`. Why did Apple decide to do it this way? I can't think of an obvious why when once explicitly asks a valued to be removed, it should still return the value registered using the `register` method? Is this just a matter of persistent vs. volatile domains?
2. Does this mean that once a key is registered using the `register` method, it is always expected to have a value?

Why can't I use `removeVolatileDomain(forName:)` to empty the entire `registrationDomain`?

```
let key = "key"
let value = "value"

UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [key: value])

// This doesn't work? registrationDomain = ["key": "value"]
UserDefaults.standard.removeVolatileDomain(forName: UserDefaults.registrationDomain)


// Why do I have to do this?
var registeredDefaults = UserDefaults.standard.volatileDomain(forName: UserDefaults.registrationDomain)
registeredDefaults[key] = nil
UserDefaults.standard.setVolatileDomain(registeredDefaults, forName: UserDefaults.registrationDomain)
// registrationDomain = [:]
```